# Ckfinder encodes URL but doesn't tell Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using CkEditor version 3.6.5 and CkFinder version 2.0.2. When I upload a file with a percent sign in it to be inserted into the editor, the file is getting uploaded as "thisis%20a%20test%20%2520%20percents.bmp" but inserted into CKEditor as "thisis a test %20 percents.bmp". I am uploading via the "insert image" button in CKEditor. Is this a bug or can I fix this somehow?

Comment: What is the original name of the image? Also, web server platform/version?

Comment: @derobert The original name of the image is what is being inserted, "thisis a test %20 percents.bmp". We're using Coldfusion 9